# How to handle Obsoletion in comments.

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I came along this post https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26605/1458 
I noticed a comment requesting some more information, followed up by a comment providing this information. As I had some spare time I decided to edit this information into the question, and flag the 2 comments as obsolete.

After one of my flags got declined today, I decided to ask for some clarification in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24878484#24878484). This led to a short discussion with [reverse Kyouko](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/28179), with the conclusion that we both have a different stance on the topic. Which brings me to the question:

### **How should we handle obsolete comments?**

As stated in [This Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/259147)

> **When should comments be deleted?**
>   Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. You should not expect them to be around forever: Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it is subject to deletion

Our current moderation whoever is maintaining a [Non-deleting culture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77379/259147)

> Comment deletion is completely intransparent. There is no way to keep track of deleted comments, or protest their deletion. As long as this is the way it is, I don't think there should be a culture of deleting comments among mods, except for the generally accepted exceptions where it takes place already: When comments are rude, or a conversation gets completely derailed and off-topic.

And all tough I can find myself in the above mentioned method as well. I do still think this is more directed at bigger comment threads which is not a common occurrence on A&M as of yet.

The way we handle these comments now, might also influence the way our community [grows](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24879433#24879433) and the [quality](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24879591#24879591) going along with this.

So what is the community opinion on this?

Comment: "Current moderation" being just me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I delete a lot of flagged obsolete comments. (Including one of the comments on that question, which I have just undeleted for clarity)

I don't mind deleting them if they are **truly *obsolete*** and provide information that is in no way useful anymore.

In this case there's a user asking the Asker to provide some information - which is then edited into the question. I think that's a perfectly acceptable reason to delete the comments - there is no benefit whatsoever in keeping them there.

I think this is probably a bigger problem on other sites where they get much more flags - to the point of not being able to empty their queue. For now I'm happy to delete them.

Comment: Of course, I have to have a different opinion to Reverse Kyouko

Comment: Different opinions lead to different reactions. This post is also meant to create a more general handling of such flags. Otherwise I could just keep flagging the same comment a few times until the other one picks it up for a change and does delete it.